# Connecting a Dell Latitude E7440 laptop to an external monitor

Tags: display

Can I connect a Dell laptop (Latitude  E7440) that uses an HDMI cable to a Dell monitor that uses a VGA cable?

Comment: This question is off topic. It is about the use of an electronics product and not about electrical engineering.

Comment: Are you thinking about building an HDMI to VGA adapter? Agreed @Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are HDMI to VGA Adapters Really Device-Specific?](http://superuser.com/questions/501222/are-hdmi-to-vga-adapters-really-device-specific), [Will an HDMI to VGA connector work?](http://superuser.com/questions/332124/will-an-hdmi-to-vga-connector-work)

Answer (score 0):

You will have better luck using the [mini-DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) port to adapt to VGA.  The 7440 has mDP right next to HDMI on the back plane of the chassis:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Googled 'Latitude E7440 vga' and the result was ' On the other hand, you’ll need to carry a VGA adapter to connect it to the old video projector in the boardroom.'